# Preventing compiling changes in imported files in LESS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

How can I prevent changes in files imported to bootstrap.less from being compiled into files, which have bootstrap.less imported?

I have custom.less file imported into bootstrap.less Each change of custom.less generates new bootstrap.css. So far so good.
But I also have another file, choosen.less, and each change of this files generates new choosen.css file - this is also expected.

The problem is that each change of custom.less generates not only the new bootstrap.css but also new choosen.css, because choosen.less imports bootstrap.less.
As final result I get duplicated code in bootstrap.css and chosen.css

So, how can I prevent from changes outside `bootstrap.less` from being compiled into `choosen.css` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're referencing `choosen.css` and `bootstrap.css` separately.

If so, you can't actually want to import Bootstrap into `choosen.css` at all.
(alternatively, simply remove the direct reference to Bootstrap)

If you want to be able to use Bootstrap mixins in `choosen.css`, just import `bootstrap/variables.less` and `bootstrap/mixins.less`.

Comment: I'm using choosen plugin (Chosen for Bootstrap and Less).
They suggest to import bootstrap into choosen:

    Import the Bootstrap library, here or in your root LESS document
    Update this path depending on your project structure
    @import "bootstrap.less";

Comment: @user1354499: My answer still applies.